# Are structured bindings reusable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.1 with `/std:c++latest /permissive-`

This simple code with structured bindings won't compile:

```
auto [a, b] = func1(x, y, z); // auto func1() -> std::tuple<double, double, double>
[a, b] = func2(x, y, z); // same signature as func2
```

saying `E1277 attributes are not allowed here`.

Code below won't compile either, same error

```
double a, b;
[a, b] = func1(x, y, z);
[a, b] = func2(x, y, z);
```

Code

```
auto [a, b] = func1(x, y, z);
auto [a, b] = func2(x, y, z);
```

won't compile as well, rightfully complaining about redefinition.

The only way it compiles is

```
auto [a1, b1] = func1(x, y, z);
auto [a2, b2] = func2(x, y, z);
```

which is, frankly, ugly.

Is this feature designed that way? Or is it VC++ bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Structured bindings must have the `auto`. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> ```
> attr(optional) cv-auto ref-operator(optional) [ identifier-list ] = expression ;
> ```
>
> ...
>   `cv-auto` -   possibly cv-qualified type specifier `auto`
>   ...

<sup>variants omitted; just changes the `= expression` part</sup>

We can see that the `cv-auto` is mandatory.

---

If you want to rebind `a` and `b`, use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
auto [a, b] = func1(x, y, z);
std::tie(a, b) = func2(x, y, z);
```